# Cutting open a Bag of Holding

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items

What happens to the items in a bag of holding if you slice it open? We had an instance where a player character placed a bag of holding over an enemies head and sliced it open.

Comment: What makes you think you can slice one open?

Comment: Your player may be familiar with earlier editions' rules for what happens to the contents of a bag of holding when it is cut open. It isn't pretty.

Answer (score 12):

### The rules are silent on this.

There are not (to the best of my knowledge) standard rules for the non-magical destruction of magic items in 4e. Additionally (and unlike D&D 3.5), the *Bag of Holding* entry says nothing about how to break it, or what happens in that circumstance.

So either magic items are not casually destructible (which is my guess), or this is a gap they left in the rules.

### I'd lean toward "magic items aren't easy to break," for two reasons.

First, the previous editions did emphasize the destruction of the Bag of Holding, to the point where it became a common joke/meme. Because of this, 4e's silence on the issue is unlikely to be an oversight.

Second, 4e's ethos does not look kindly of the casual elimination of character power and agency.

### So what happens to the objects inside a Bag of Holding if it *is* somehow broken?

That's up to the individual group to decide; there are no explicit rules to follow.

Answer (score -4):

In a certain campaign, there was a cult dedicated to a chaotic god from the Outer planes. There was a specific ritual that demanded you put 10,000gp worth of treasure inside a bag of holding and then slice it open.

The items stored inside were then lost in a strange dimension as an offering to the god.

Comment: Do you have the rules citation for that ritual?

Comment: Is this campaign for D&D 4e?